# Base/Derived template class types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance

I have a template class that is built around a `std::vector`.  It looks like...

```
template <class T>
class Vector {
public:
    std::vector<T> vec;

    // Constructors...
    // Operator overloads...
    // Methods...
    // etc.
};
```

I want to create a derived template class, `ComplexVector` that will require the data type to be `std::complex<T>`, and of course I want to reuse the methods, operator overloads, etc., that I created in class `Vector`.

The problem is that it seems like there are two ways of doing this.

1) Force the declaration of `std::complex<T>` as the template type.

```
ComplexVector< std::complex<float> > myVec;
```

2) Declare `ComplexVector` with just the the scalar type, but then pass the `std::complex` type to the `Vector` constructor.

```
ComplexVector<float> myVec;
// Constructor
ComplexVector<T>::ComplexVector() : Vector< std::complex<T> >
```

Option 1 is far simpler in terms of developing the software but it is ugly for the user, while option 2 is a lot nicer for the user.  I would like to do option #2, but I'm worried about how it will work out.

If I pass `std::vector<T>` to the base class' constructor, will that only change what the constructor does, or will the entire template go from type `T` to `std::complex< T >`?

If it doesn't all convert to `std::complex<T>`, does that mean that I would have to overload all of the methods that are in `Vector`?

Comment: How about specialize `Vector` for complex types ?

Comment: I think that constructor is not the right term, I think you hesitate between #1 `template <typename T> ComplexVector<T> : Vector<T> { static_assert(is_complex<T>::value); /*..*/};` and #2 `template <typename U> ComplexVector<U> : Vector<std::complex<U>> { /*..*/};`.

Comment: `template <typename T> using ComplexVector = Vector<std::complex<T>>;` perhaps? However, with the "simplified" syntax of `ComplexVector<float>`, it's not clear how you plan to express "or any complex data type that behaves similarly to `std::complex<T>`" part of the requirements.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You're right, with option #2 it would have to be std::complex.

Comment: @Jarod42 I wasn't aware of template specialization.  It looks like that might be the way to go.

Comment: @Jarod42 So the way it would work is to have the "complex only" methods have the default behavior of just doing "assert(false)", but if the template type happens to be std::complex then the specialized method would do its thing?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve. Suggested `template <typename T> using ComplexVector = Vector<std::complex<T>>;` seems to be exactly what you ask for.

Comment: It seems you want the template to only work for std::complex<T>, why? Or in other words, if someone makes a class, myComplex, similar to std::complex<T> why shouldn't  ComplexVector<myComplex> work?

Comment: @HansOlsson If there's a clean way to make ComplexVector<myComplex> work that also works for ComplexVector<T>, I'm open to that.

Comment: @JimClay Have a read about duck typing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing . Templates in C++ are duck typed, meaning people don't usually try to restrict what kind of arguments they take. For example, `string` is an alias for `basic_string<char>`... and you can instantiate `basic_string<C>` for any class C that is sufficiently like a char, inc. user-defined classes.  I think this should be fine in your case.

Comment: From comments below it looks like you want to add a specific method to the complex vector. Can you tell us exactly what that method is? (Maybe the norm?)

Comment: @Mohan Things like "fft".

Comment: @JimClay I think that deriving isn't really the appropriate solution here. I can't fit this explanation into a comment, so I've made an answer (though I know you've accepted one).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Templated typedef

If you don't really want to have specialization, you can simply use a templated typedef like so:

```
template <typename T>
using ComplexVector = Vector<std::complex<T>>;
```

Users could then use `ComplexVector<float>` and it would properly represent a `Vector<std::complex<T>>`.
This is a very simple solution which doesn't quite fit your needs. Take a look at the following solutions for your specific problem.

## Templated inheritence

If your goal is to only change specific methods when `T` is `std::complex<U>`, you have to inherit from `Vector` like so:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector
{
    public:
    bool is_complex() { return false; }
};

template <typename U>
class ComplexVector : Vector<std::complex<U>>
{
  public:
    bool is_complex() { return true; }
};
```

This also allows you to add methods only available to `complex`-based Vectors.

## Adding a method for `ComplexVector` only

If you want to be able to "enhance" `ComplexVector`, you can do it like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

template <typename T>
class Vector
{
  public:
    bool is_complex() { return false; }
};

template <typename U>
class ComplexVector : Vector<std::complex<U>>
{
  public:
    bool is_complex() { return true; }
    bool only_for_complex() { return true; } // Only in ComplexVector
};

int main() {
  Vector<float> float_vec;
  ComplexVector<float> complex_vec;

  std::cout << "Is float_vec complex? " << float_vec.is_complex() << "\n";
  std::cout << "Is complex_vec complex? " << complex_vec.is_complex() << "\n";

  // The following line doesn't compile
  // std::cout << "Is only_for_complex method in float_vec? " << float_vec.only_for_complex() << "\n";
  std::cout << "Is only_for_complex method in complex_vec? " << complex_vec.only_for_complex() << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

[Working demo here](https://ideone.com/ipkfDh)

### Using a small type trait to check the type

Using some templating, we can create a small helper to determine whether a given type is a `ComplexVector` or not. This could come in handy if you want to call the specific methods safely in a template heavy environment:

```
// For any type T, value is false.
template <typename T>
struct is_complex_vector
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

// We specialize the struct so that, for any type U,
// passing ComplexVector<U> makes value true
template <>
template <typename U>
struct is_complex_vector<ComplexVector<U>>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

is_complex_vector<typeof(float_vec)>::value; // is false
is_complex_vector<typeof(complex_vec)>::value; // is true
```

[Here is another small demo to demonstrate this behavior in practice](https://ideone.com/Kj165n)
`value` will be determined at compile. This could allow you to use some [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) tricks in order to better control the flow of your program. (Or you can use the [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) if you are using [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17).)

Comment: The "using" notation looks attractive, but I take it that it's, as you say, simply a typedef, so I wouldn't be able to add functions to ComplexVector?

Comment: No, you wouldn't be able to add functions. Let me update with an example for adding methods to ComplexVector.

Comment: @JimClay I've edited my answer to add a live example of adding a function to the `ComplexVector` class.

Answer (score 5):

I think you’re confused by using the name T twice. Look at this this way:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector
{ ... }

template<typename U>
class ComplexVector : public Vector<std::complex<U>>
{ ... }

ComplexVector<float>; // U = float, T = std::complex<float>
```

Comment: You could have the same Result with `using` declaration without the need of inheritance...

Comment: @Jaa-c: from the comments it seems the writer intends to add functions to the complex only version, hence inheritance is required.

Comment: That's correct, I want to add functions to the complex only version.

Comment: So if I do it this way, the entire template type for Vector becomes "std::complex<U>"?  I'm glad that it works that way, it just seems weird that the base class and the derived class can have different template types.

Comment: @JimClay they are different templates. It's just natural that different templates may have different type parameters. Think of it this way: whenever `ComplexVector` is instantiated, it instantiates a `Vector<std::complex<U>>` and uses it as a base class. You're doing the same in `Vector`: you instantiate a `std::vector<T>` whenever your Vector is instantiated, except you're using it as a member, instead of as a base class.

Answer (score 2):

In [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230872/base-derived-template-class-types?noredirect=1#comment91576914_52230872) on the original q., @JimClay clarifies the use case: he wants to extend the complex vector with methods like `fft` (Fast Fourier Transform).

It is certainly possible to derive from `vector<T>` to create a new class, say, `ComplexVector<T>` and add a method like `fft`, but I don't recommend it. Detailed reasons below. A better alternative is to add a standalone function like

```
template<typename T>
vector<complex<T>> fft(const vector<complex<T>>&);
```

(that's with `using namespace std` for readability).

Here are the **reasons not to use a derived template class**:

- Suppose you want to use a library function that returns a `vector<complex<T>>` `v`. If you've rolled your own `ComplexVector<T>`, you'll need to take `v` and convert it to a `ComplexVector<T>` before calling `fft`. This *can* be done efficiently, but it requires users to be careful with move construction.
- It gets worse. Suppose you and I are in the same situation, and both roll our own classes, `MyComplexVector<T>` and `YourComplexVector<T>`. Then users who want to use our libraries together will need to take the `MyComplexVector<T>`, convert it to a `vector<T>`, and then convert to a `YourComplexVector<T>` before calling my library. [Though the first conversion will happen implicitly in most cases.]
- Users will need to do work to familiarise themselves with the semantics of `ComplexVector<T>`, whereas every C++ programmer knows how `vector<T>` behaves.

I'm old enough to have used C++ before the STL, and using libraries together was not fun! Indeed, library interoperability was one of the main reasons for the introduction of the standard `string`, `vector`, etc..

Note that if you want to implement an efficient in-place `fft`, you'll want a rvalue-reference version:

```
template<typename T>
vector<complex<T>> fft(vector<complex<T>>&&);
```

Comment: You make a good point, but I'll actually probably end up doing both (rolling my own class and creating an algorithm function that will use random access iterators to do an FFT).  The reason for both is that I'm going to extend it to FFT's on matrices, and I need to use iterators to make that generalizable and reasonably efficient.

Comment: @JimClay If you have the version that accepts iterators, why roll your own class as well? What does it add?

Comment: The primary reason, honestly, is that I'm doing it for fun.  There are some practical reasons too though.  1) I'm not just doing FFT's, there are quite a few other methods that I'm doing. Could I do them as algorithms too?  Maybe.  I'll have to think about that.  2) There is no std::matrix, so I either have to roll my own or use someone else's.  I'm rolling my own and creating a customized random access iterator for it that can iterate across rows or down columns while hiding the fact that the data structure for the matrix is really a std::vector.

Comment: I've already got the Matrix class and the custom iterator up and running, by the way, and it's kind of cool to see std::sort work on them with no hitches.

Comment: @JimClay If you're having fun then I am not going to say any more!! Though I am curious what methods would be tricky to implement as standalone functions.

Comment: One example is filtering (aka convolution).  Filtering naturally creates "tails", so the final vector is bigger than the starting vector.  Also, you can filter a "stream" of samples represented by multiple vectors of data, but to do that you have to remember certain information when going from one vector to the next.

Comment: I don't think algorithms really have a way of addressing situations like that, though if I'm wrong I'm happy to learn more about it.

Comment: @JimClay there's no reason why the output vector from a function has to be the same size as the input vector. So convolution isn't an issue.  More generally, there's nothing magic about methods that lets them do anything that functions don't, EXCEPT have access to private data. Which isn't an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

`ComplexVector<std::complex<T> >` is redundant (you already said it was a complex vector right ?).

Using the general convention you will arrive at:

```
class ComplexVector< T > : public Vector< std::complex<T> > {
public:
  typedef std::complex<T> type;//for convenience, etc.
  //...
}
```

Adding specialization of Vector(as some suggested), while also inheriting is not directly possible and a (perhaps difficult) refactor is needed involving `Vector<T>`- but basicly it involves moving most/all parts to a new common base class. It might be a good idea if you are already doing work on `Vector<T>` for example.